# MobileFirst 7.0 CLI - Unable to Start Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I'm running into issues trying to preview the mobilefirst app. I was able to run and preview the app earlier but not sure what changed.

```
mfp start -dd
mobilefirst-cli verb cli process.argv=["/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/IBMnode/bin/node","/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/bin/mobilefirst-cli.js","start","-dd"]
mobilefirst-cli verb cli opts={"ddebug":true,"argv":{"remain":["start"],"cooked":["start","--ddebug"],"original":["start","-dd"]}}
mobilefirst-cli verb cli mobilefirst@7.0.0.00.20150430-1604
mobilefirst-cli verb cli node@v0.10.30
Initializing MobileFirst Console.
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dbasedir=/Users/extremeblueaustin/Walmart/2015-walmart/mobile
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.jars.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=9.41.78.128
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task build-WAR
Buildfile: /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml

build-WAR:
     [echo] Building worklight WAR for project mobile
mobilefirst-cli verb cli finish with mobilefirst start
mobilefirst-cli verb code 1
```

When I go to build and preview, it says to run 'mobilefirst start'.

```
mfp preview -d
mobilefirst-cli verb cli process.argv=["/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/IBMnode/bin/node","/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/bin/mobilefirst-cli.js","preview","-d"]
mobilefirst-cli verb cli opts={"debug":true,"argv":{"remain":["preview"],"cooked":["preview","--debug"],"original":["preview","-d"]}}
mobilefirst-cli verb cli mobilefirst@7.0.0.00.20150430-1604
mobilefirst-cli verb cli node@v0.10.30
mobilefirst-cli verb cli start with 
mobilefirst preview
Initializing MobileFirst Console.
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables - Dbasedir=/Users/user/folder/folder/mobile ** redacted **
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.jars.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=9.41.78.128
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task build-WAR
Buildfile: /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml

build-WAR:
 [echo] Building worklight WAR for project mobile
Error: The MobileFirst server that you have configured does not appear to be running. Start the server with 'mobilefirst start'.
mobilefirst-cli verb cli finish with mobilefirst preview
mobilefirst-cli verb code 126
```

Let me know what else is needed and I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to jdk directory. This same issue occurred to me when I lacked the `JAVA_HOME` in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problemn installing the JDK 7.
I used the JDK 8.

Check this: [mobile first cli project deploy failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284767/mobile-first-cli-project-deploy-failing)