# mobile first cli project deploy failing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

when i try to deploy my project using MFP CLI it gives the following error

```
xxxx-Macmini:Nauth user-x$  mfp  build  
App Nauth was successfully built.

xxxx-Macmini:Nauth user-x$  mfp deploy  
Initializing MobileFirst Console  
Error: The MobileFirst server that you have configured does not appear to be running. Start the server with 'mobilefirst start'.
```

**mfp info**

> xxxx-Macmini:Nauth user-x$ mfp info
>  OS: darwin x64 Release: 11.4.2
>   System Memory: 128 MB free out of 4096 MB Node: v0.10.30 MobileFirst
>   CLI: 7.0.0.00.20150610-1400 Current directory:
>   /Volumes/Development/wlsamples/NAuth2/apps/Nauth
>
> Current project: /Volumes/Development/wlsamples/NAuth2
>
> Adapter: SqlAuth
>   (/Volumes/Development/wlsamples/NAuth2/adapters/SqlAuth/SqlAuth.xml)
>   Description: SqlAuth Type: sql Procedures: readuser,
>   submitAuthentication, getBalance
>
> Application: Nauth
>   (/Volumes/Development/wlsamples/NAuth2/apps/Nauth/application-descriptor.xml)
>   Description: Nauth Type: hybrid application Features:  Environments:
>   iphone Skins:
>
> Server location:
>   /Users/user-x/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150610-1353/server Server
>   binary:
>   /Users/user-x/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150610-1353/server/wlp/bin/server
>   MobileFirst instance:
>   /Users/user-x/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150610-1353/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight
>   objc[26232]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
>   and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. WebSphere
>   Application Server 8.5.5.4 (1.0.7.cl50420141121-1414) on Java
>   HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_45-b14 (en_US)
>
> Environment variables: TERM_PROGRAM: Apple_Terminal rvm_bin_path:
>   /Users/user-x/.rvm/bin TERM: xterm-256color SHELL: /bin/bash TMPDIR:
>   /var/folders/0m/ftx97h0n1rbcdwb3b3sv18lm0000gn/T/
>   Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render: /tmp/launch-pbGaeh/Render
>   TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: 303.2 TERM_SESSION_ID:
>   8CB82941-523E-4034-BCA0-470F186ED261 USER: user-x COMMAND_MODE:
>   unix2003
>   _system_type: Darwin rvm_path: /Users/user-x/.rvm SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/launch-n9tSIx/Listeners
>   __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING: 0x1F5:0:0 Apple_Ubiquity_Message: /tmp/launch-bCTtmF/Apple_Ubiquity_Message WEBWORKS_HOME:
>   /Applications/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15 rvm_prefix: /Users/user-x
>   PATH: /Applications/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15:/Applications/BB10
>   WebWorks SDK
>   2.2.0.15/cordova-blackberry/bin/dependencies/bb-tools/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI:/Users/user-x/.rvm/bin
>   PWD: /Volumes/Development/wlsamples/NAuth2/apps/Nauth JAVA_HOME:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
>   _system_arch: i386
>   _system_version: 10.7 rvm_version: 1.26.11 (latest) SHLVL: 2 HOME: /Users/user-x LOGNAME: user-x LC_CTYPE: UTF-8 DISPLAY:
>   /tmp/launch-BI7HzF/org.x:0
>   _system_name: OSX
>   _: /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/IBMnode/bin/node WLP_USER_DIR: /Users/user-x/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150610-1353/server/wlp/usr
>   
>  
>  **Java home is set properly** 
>  xxxx-Macmini:Nauth
>   user-x$ echo $JAVA_HOME
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. MobileFirst Platform Foundation does not support Java 8 - you may only use Java 6 or 7.
2. After doing (1), also uninstall the CLI (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/Uninstaller) and download the latest available iFix from IBM Fix Central which contains several bug fixes for the CLI, including a potential fix for the server mentioned in the question.